# Why do we need Perl DBI functions that return 1 row?

Tags: perl, dbi, dbix-class

I was looking into Perl's DBI and I saw the following methods:
[selectrow_array](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#selectrow_array)
[selectrow_arrayref](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#selectrow_arrayref)
[selectrow_hashref](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#selectrow_hashref)
All these return 1 row from the result set. So I don't understand what is their usefulness. Are they some kind of replacement of doing a `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: The answers below are good. You should still add LIMIT 1 to the query if it would return many rows so the server can avoid selecting and sending many rows back to the client.

Answer (score 10):

There is a lot of examples where is useful get only one row, and these functions simplify the search process. For example, to get the count of a result set

```
my $sql = "select count(*) from people where age>?";    
my ($count) = $dbh->selectrow_array($sql, undef, 42);
```

The alternative requires: prepare, bind & execute, fetch and finish.

Comment: It also makes clear that I'm expecting only a single row, without having to look at `$sql`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's just a syntaxic sugar to make the program smaller, when you need to select only 1 row. As the manual says:

> selectrow_hashref - This utility method combines "prepare", "execute" and
>   "fetchrow_hashref"

So, instead of writing say:

```
$sql = qq{
    SELECT
        project.domain,
        project.pages_to_save,
        project.pages_to_check,
        IFNULL(project.no_exact_result, 0) AS no_exact_result
    FROM
        project
    WHERE
        project.id=?
};
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($project_id);
my $values_ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
$sth->finish();
```

You can write:

```
$sql = qq{
    SELECT
        project.domain,
        project.pages_to_save,
        project.pages_to_check,
        IFNULL(project.no_exact_result, 0) AS no_exact_result
    FROM
        project
    WHERE
        project.id=?
};
my $values_ref = $sth->selectrow_hashref($sql, undef, $project_id);
```

Comment: How do you know that the `project.id=?` will return 1 row?

Comment: @Jim Because in my database id is the primary key in project table